# Compare 2 array and change the property value

Tags: javascript

there are 2 array refArr and finalArr. I need to change the value of "external" in finalArr based on the refArr. if the value of "external" is true in refArr then the value of "external" should change true in finalArr or if the "external" is false in refArr it should change to false in finalArr. In the finalArr if the value of "Editable" is false that object is untouched.

```
let refArr = [
    {number: "8088",external: true,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"},
    {number: "8089",external: true,Editable: true,  type: "efg"},
    {number: "8080",external: false,Editable: true,  type: "hij"}
]

let finalArr = [
    {number: "6543",external: false,Editable: false, type: "xyz"},
    {number: "8089",external: false,Editable: true, type: "efg"},
    {number: "8080",external: true,Editable: true, type: "hij"},
    {number: "8088",external: false,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"},
    {number: "8088",external: false,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"}
]

this is the final output in need 

finalArr = [
    {number: "6543",external: false,Editable: false, type: "xyz"},
    {number: "8089",external: true,Editable: true, type: "efg"},
    {number: "8080",external: false,Editable: true, type: "hij"},
    {number: "8088",external: true,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"},
    {number: "8088",external: true,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"}
]
```

I am not able to get the logic to change the value in finalArr base on the refArr.

Comment: Please show what you've tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't want to mutate the original `finalArr`:

```js
const tmp = finalArr.map( x => {
  const match = refArr.find( y => y.number === x.number);

  if ((x.Editable && match) && x.external !== match.external) {
      x.external = match.external;
    }

  return x;
});
```

If you don't care if `finalArr` is mutated:

```js
finalArr.forEach( x => {
  const match = refArr.find( y => y.number === x.number);

  if ((x.Editable && match) && x.external !== match.external) {
      x.external = match.external;
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Or this old school nested loop ...

```js
let refArr = [
    {number: "8088",external: true,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"},
    {number: "8089",external: true,Editable: true,  type: "efg"},
    {number: "8080",external: false,Editable: true,  type: "hij"}
]

let finalArr = [
    {number: "6543",external: false,Editable: false, type: "xyz"},
    {number: "8089",external: false,Editable: true, type: "efg"},
    {number: "8080",external: true,Editable: true, type: "hij"},
    {number: "8088",external: false,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"},
    {number: "8088",external: false,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"}
]

for(let i = 0; i < finalArr.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < refArr.length; j++) {
        if(finalArr[i].number === refArr[j].number) {
            finalArr[i].external = refArr[j].external
        }
    }
}
console.log(finalArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does not mutate the original and does not reference objects in the original array.

Using Array#map, Array#find, destructuring, and spread syntax.

```js
const ref=[{number:"8088",external:!0,Editable:!0,type:"Abcd"},{number:"8089",external:!0,Editable:!0,type:"efg"},{number:"8080",external:!1,Editable:!0,type:"hij"}]
const data=[{number:"6543",external:!1,Editable:!1,type:"xyz"},{number:"8089",external:!1,Editable:!0,type:"efg"},{number:"8080",external:!0,Editable:!0,type:"hij"},{number:"8088",external:!1,Editable:!0,type:"Abcd"},{number:"8088",external:!1,Editable:!0,type:"Abcd"}];

const res = data.map(({external, ...o})=>{
   const r = ref.find(({number})=>number===o.number);
   if(r && r.Editable){
      return {...o, external: r.external}
   }
   return {...o, external}
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I'll give you one.  I didn't get any <3 either.

Comment: Back atcha @kemicofa

Answer (score 0):

```js
let refArr = [
    {number: "8088",external: true,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"},
    {number: "8089",external: true,Editable: true,  type: "efg"},
    {number: "8080",external: false,Editable: true,  type: "hij"}
]

let finalArr = [
    {number: "6543",external: false,Editable: false, type: "xyz"},
    {number: "8089",external: false,Editable: true, type: "efg"},
    {number: "8080",external: true,Editable: true, type: "hij"},
    {number: "8088",external: false,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"},
    {number: "8088",external: false,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"}
]

finalArr.forEach(x => {
    if(!x.Editable) return;
    const ref = refArr.find(y => y.number === x.number);
    if(!ref) return;
    
    if(ref.external === true) x.external = !x.external;
})

console.log(finalArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let refArr = [
    {number: "8088",external: true,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"},
    {number: "8089",external: true,Editable: true,  type: "efg"},
    {number: "8080",external: false,Editable: true,  type: "hij"}
]

let finalArr = [
    {number: "6543",external: false,Editable: false, type: "xyz"},
    {number: "8089",external: false,Editable: true, type: "efg"},
    {number: "8080",external: true,Editable: true, type: "hij"},
    {number: "8088",external: false,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"},
    {number: "8088",external: false,Editable: true, type: "Abcd"}
]

let result = finalArr.map((f) => {
    if (f.Editable) {
        const ref = refArr.find(r => r.number == f.number);
        f.external = ref.external;
    }

    return f;
});

console.log(result);
```